# How many characters should I reserve in my database for storing SHA512 hash?

Tags: security, passwords, sha, sha512

Column: pwdhash

Type: char

Many web pages give me the bit size, not a character size.
Should I use a **binary** field instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**64 bytes** when stored in BLOB.

**128 characters** when stored as hex.

**~88 characters** when stored as [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use a binary field.
A hash is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

For readability reasons, these are sometimes stored as hexadecimal digits (two digits per byte).  So 512 bits requires 64 bytes, which would need a `char(128)` field.  If you used a binary field, it would only need 64 bytes.